# Which one is the valid data binding symbol "android:text="@={prop}"" or "android:text="@{prop}""

Tags: android

I read the tutorial about data binding just like the below sample from android developers

```
   <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@{user.firstName}"
       android:onClick="@{handlers::onClickFriend}"/>
```

But as I implement the data binding function on TextInputLayout xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/user_id_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_normal">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/input_user_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="@={viewmodel.userName}"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_username" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and declare the variable in viewmodel

```
public final ObservableField<String> userName = new ObservableField<>();
```

While I call the `userName.get()`, it always gives me `null`.

---

However, I only change the data binding syntax from

```
android:text="@{viewmodel.password}"
```

to

```
android:text="@={viewmodel.password}"
```

my `userName.get()` finally return the user input value.

Why it happened?

Comment: This one is right:  android:text="@{user.firstName}"

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, the `android:text="@={viewmodel.userName}"` is used for two-way data binding (where data can come from the program or from the layout), and where you can get updated from data in real time, by using Observable.

On the other hand, the `android:text="@{viewmodel.userName}"` used for the simple value, where you set the value manually using simple data type (like String, etc).

Thus because you are using Observable, you must use the `@=`.